# Google analytics 3.08 IOS idfa class missing, won't collect idfa

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, google-analytics, console

I downloaded google analytics and i followed their instructions how to implement analytics in application. But whatever i tried i get this log in xcode: `idfa class missing, won't collect idfa`.

[image: Screenshot for console message]

So i google it and found that apple will reject apps that have this warning. I also discovered that google fixed this issue with 3.03c release, and that we don't have to import library that uses ads. I have also run their example and i get same log in their example.

So my question is, will Apple approve my application, how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have the same issue. It seams that 3.08 lib is linked with iAd.Framework
Here is what I did - I've rolled back to the version 3.03c. You can download it here
"https://dl.google.com/googleanalyticsservices/GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.03c.zip

The best way is to use [Cocopoads](http://cocoapods.org) for managing libraries with `pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '3.0.3c'`

Comment: I'm using 3.0.3c. I don't want to use IDFA, do you know how to get App past Apple's review? They are rejecting it, they say to remove any instances of advertisingIdentifier and stuff.

Comment: Kevin Delord's solution solves this problem without having to update to an older SDK, which

Comment: That's would work BUT. than you have to specify why are you using IDFA when you will publish your app to App Store. You APP is using advertising but actually it's not. So won't go for that solution.

Comment: Still an issue in 3.10. I switched to 3.0.3c as you suggested and the warning went away. I don't want to be adding iAd libraries into my project if I am not using them!

Comment: Using pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10' also takes that warning away.

Comment: You shouldn't roll back your code, just you couldn't resolve this issue properly.

Comment: Instead of linking it by hand, you should use new Pods from Google, which include pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'

Answer (score 18):

I am using `3.0.9`. I was able to remove the warning by linking in the `libAdIdAccess.a` library provided with the `GoogleAnalytics SDK` and the `AdSupport.framework`.

Comment: If you upgrade to 3.10 version, then replace googleAnalyticsHeader folder with downloaded one. This contains 'libAdIdAccess.a' and 'GAIEcommerceProductAction'& 'GAIEcommerceFields' as additional files.

Answer (score 17):

I am using the version `3.0.9` and to get rid of this warning I had to link the library `libAdIdAccess.a` and the `AdSupport.framework` manually.

To do so simply add the following lines into your build settings `Other Linker Flags` (OTHER_LDFLAGS) :

> -framework AdSupport
>
> -force_load "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK/libAdIdAccess.a"

It should look like this:
[image]

Link: [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers)

Comment: I installed google analytics via cocoapods and apparently `libAdIdAccess.a` did not come included with the framework, so in addition to this solution I had to download the framework and manually place the library in the specified location. this got rid of the warning.

Comment: As of version 3.10, if you install Google Analytics via CocoaPods you can install its subspec via 
`pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK/IDFA'` and `libAdIdAccess` will be added to your project automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just for complete other responses. I'm using the Google Analytics SDK v3.09 which I integrated without CocoaPod within Xcode 6.
In order to remove the warning, I simply added the libAdIdAccess.a static library to my project by a drag and drop.

AdSupport.framework was already included in my project.

Note: I don't know why but sometimes, Xcode is mistaken for path adding an new library by this way what is resulting into a link error. In this case just modify the path in the Library Search Path option from the Build Settings :  replace `$(PROJECT_DIR)/YourDirectory/GoogleAnalyticsLibrary-3.09` by `"$(SRCROOT)/YourDirectory/GoogleAnalyticsLibrary-3.09"`

Comment: Dragging in libAdIdAccess.a was just the ticket! Thanks. :]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using v3.08 and get the same warning.  I just submitted my app and it was approved by Apple.  I think they are aware of the issue but did not enforce it in my case.  You can submit your app and take the time between submission and decision to remove 3.08 and go back to 3.03c just in case they reject it.

Answer (score 1):

> GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK has been deprecated in favor of
>   GoogleAnalytics

so just replace the line in your pod file to

```
 pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add `libAdIdAccess.a` to your project. It is part of `GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.09` delivery.

Answer (score 0):

pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'

That will let cocoapods get what you need. I havent had to do the force_load of it either.

Installing GoogleIDFASupport (3.14.0)
Using GoogleTagManager (3.15.0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3.0.3c and not using IDFA,.

Howerer, "idfa class missing" is still logged.

```
GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
```

I solved the problem by trying to delete the line above.

Answer (score -3):

I am using 3.0.9. Per Google documentation you need to set tracker.allowIDFACollection to NO on each tracker.

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = NO;
```

This will remove the warning.

Comment: I tried using 3.0.9 and I still get the warning as the very first item in the console.  Also, the header states that this value is by default set to NO (false).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I am using 3.0.9 installed via CocoaPods.

Comment: I think you need to link in the libAdIdAccess.a library that Googke provided.