# Differences between AppView and ScreenView in GoogleAnalytics iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-analytics, xcode5

I'm using Google Analytics ***3.0.9*** iOS SDK for my iPhone app developement. I found some issues with idfa. So, iam moving to 3.0.3c as suggested from [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955138/google-analytics-3-08-ios-idfa-class-missing-wont-collect-idfa).

While implementing the ***3.0.3c*** SDK, i found the error "no known class method for selector **'create screenview'**.

In the line :

```
**[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];**
```

iam supposed to change as

```
**[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];**
```

If the change is supposed to done, iam not getting the tracking correctly as previous.
What i supposed to do for implementing analytics without these issues. If possible may i know the differences between these sdk's and between screenview and appview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now GA used for Advanced Configuration

**Managing Sessions with defaults to 30 minutes**

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]]
```

this is used for Data is sent to Google Analytics by setting maps of parameter-value pairs on the tracker and sending them via the set and send methods:

```
 //it is used in all hits sent from this screen  //this is  used for V3
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"MainMenu Screen"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

**Managing Sessions with manually**

```
To manually start or end a session


// Start a new session with a screenView hit.
GAIDictionaryBuilder *builder = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView];
[builder set:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"MainMenu Screen"];
[tracker send:[builder build]];
```

Comment: k friend have a happy day