# idfa class missing, won't collect idfa

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, idfa

The following log entry is appearing when using the Google Analytics SDK for iOS (version 3.09):

```
idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
```

Is there any way to remove this log entry without including the `AdSupport.frameork` as I want to use analytics without showing any ads or using the IDFA.

Comment: this has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955138/google-analytics-3-08-ios-idfa-class-missing-wont-collect-idfa