# GoogleAnalytics 3.10 - How to remove IDFA warning from logs?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, iad, google-analytics-sdk

I am developing an app in which i have added GoogleAnalytics 3.10 library.

But whenever i try to run the app i see warning in my logs -

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
```

as per Apple's guideline if you are using IDFA other than advertising purpose your app may get rejected.

I have looked for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955138/google-analytics-3-08-ios-idfa-class-missing-wont-collect-idfa) solution but it will not work for me. Because 3.03c don't have `GAIEcommerceFields.h` and its related classes.

I haven't linked `iAd.framework` , `AdSupport.framework` or `libAdIdAccess.a` in my project.

My question is how to get rid of this warning?
If its not possible to remove this warning them will apple approve my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the log level to info or below:

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelInfo];
```

Comment: @Hans One By setting the log level to kGAILogLevelInfo you don't solve the root issue but turns off the issue logging. So the issue is still present.

Comment: @dzensik Yes, but afaik the issue is not a real/serious issue. It's just a hint that idfa won't be collected - like message says: "VERBOSE ..."